# Activity Monitor confusion

Tags: macos, terminal, java

I have two java programs that run forever until I terminate the process, I start both at once using a script....

```
Cobrakai$more  startCapture
nohup startCaptureA.sh &
nohup startCaptureB.sh &
Cobrakai$more startCaptureA.sh 
cd ~/Dropbox/Eclipse/workspace/com.tmc.personal.screencapture/bin
java com/tmc/personal/ScreenCapture
Cobrakai$more startCaptureB.sh 
cd ~/Dropbox/Eclipse/workspace/com.tmc.personal.screencapture/bin
java com/tmc/personal/ActiveWindowCapture
```

They both continue to run, I can see the output they generate (they write to a file each), and I can see them in 'ps':

```
Cobrakai$ps x  | grep Capture | grep java
 1137 s000  S      0:12.13 /usr/bin/java com/tmc/personal/ScreenCapture
 1138 s000  S      0:05.17 /usr/bin/java com/tmc/personal/ActiveWindowCapture
Cobrakai$
```

But when I open Activity Monitor, I can see that 'ScreenCapture' is running (and taking 96MB of memory)

[image]

But 'ActiveWindowCapture' does not appear at all... 
[image]

Can someone tell me why it's not appearing? I'm deeply lost...

EDIT - following (sensible) suggestion from the comments, I tried just starting ActiveWindowManager

```
Cobrakai$killall java
Cobrakai$ps x  | grep Capture | grep java
[1]-  Exit 143                nohup startCaptureB.sh
[2]+  Exit 143                nohup startCaptureA.sh
Cobrakai$nohup startCaptureB.sh &
[1] 3070
Cobrakai$appending output to nohup.out

Cobrakai$ps x  | grep Capture | grep java
 3071 s000  S      0:00.23 /usr/bin/java com/tmc/personal/ActiveWindowCapture
Cobrakai$
```

But still nothing in the Activity Monitor...:s

Comment: Try opening the applications in reverse order (i.e. open ActiveWindowCapture before ScreenCapture) and see if the opposite effect occurs. I think it has something to do with there being a single java process to "rule them all."

Comment: Have you got any java processes in Activity monitor it might be showing as that

Comment: @XAleXOwnZX edited question to cover... :)

Comment: Did you try sorting Activity Monitor by PID and see whether the process has a different name there?

Comment: That second grep implies that ScreenCapture is not running and it is not an ActivityMonitor issue are you sure that the programs are not exiting?

Comment: Hi Mark - Screen Capture wasn't running for the second grep - that edit was to test the possibility that @XAleXOwnZX suggested...

Comment: Which versions of OS X and Java are you running?